# How to access values in nested JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, nested

I have a nested json data. Since I am kinda new to the whole js - json logic, I can't make my app work as I want and after many research, I could not find the solution for my problem.

On this image, you can see the data:

[image]

I want to access, for example "TYPE" property of every single currency in "RAW". (via ngFor)

How should I do it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What exactly you want? how you need your expected output?

Comment: I want to get the value of specific key, in this case key "TYPE". It would be great to get it via ngFor loop, but it could be done as maybe some sort of json to array method, and then acces through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example (Image in your question), you can create an [`Angular Pipe`](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'ObjKeys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

**Imagine this variable following your structure**

```
let object = {
  "RAW": {
    "ETH": {
      "USD": {
        "TYPE": 5
      }
    },
    "DASH": {
      "USD": {
        "TYPE": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Then in your HTML template**

```
<p *ngFor="let key of object.RAW | ObjKeys">
  Type for {{key}}<br>
  {{object.RAW[key]["USD"]["TYPE"]}}
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works flawlessly

Comment: @sebamed Great!!